# How to adjust siblings spacing in TikZ graph?

Tags: tikz-trees

I have drawn the following right expanding tree graph in beamer, but its branches overlap each other. I have tried the sibling distance option but don't get the required results. Does anyone have an idea about how to do this correctly?.

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\begin{frame}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]  
\node {Start O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
child{node[anchor=west]{O Success Node}}  
}  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node{dead End}}  
}}}}  
child{node{O}  
[grow=right]  
child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
}  
}%-----------------------------  
child{node{O}}  
[grow = right]  
child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}  
child{node{O}}  
[grow = right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow = right]  
child{node{O}  
[grow = right]  
child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}}  
child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}  
}  
child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}  
;  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
```

Comment: For the next time, use a MWE that can be compiled without further modification, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your tree, `O` is node, other text are labels. Than the tree drawing with plain `tikz` is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,
every  node/.append style = {inner sep=1pt, anchor=west},
every label/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, font=\small},
grow=right,
level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=28mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=14mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance= 6mm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance= 4mm},
]
\node[label=left:Start, anchor=east] {O}
    % lover part
    child{node{O}
        child{node{O}
            child{node{O}
                child{node[label=right:Dead End]     {O}}
                child{node[label={[font=\bfseries]right:Success Node}] {O}}
                }
            child{node{O}
                child{node{O}
                    child{node{O}
                        child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        child{node{O}
            child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
            child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
            child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
            }
        }
    % upper part
    child{node{O}
        child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
        child{node{O}
            child{node{O}
                child{node{O}
                    child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
                    }
                child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
                }
            child{node[label=right:Dead End] {O}}
            }
        }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and with `forest`, where I assume, that nodes are circles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
        % style of tree nodes
        circle, draw, inner sep=3pt,
        every label/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, font=\small},
        %
        grow=east,
        %child anchor=west, parent anchor=east,
        s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
    where level={1}{s sep=6mm}{},
    where level={2}{s sep=3mm}{},
        l sep = 9mm,    % level distance
         edge = {-latex},
        }
    [ , label=left:Start
        [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    [ 
                        [ 
                            [ , label=right:Dead End]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                [ 
                    [ , label={[font=\bfseries]right:Sucess Node}]
                    [ , label=right:Dead End]
                ]
            ]
            [ 
                [ , label=right:Dead End]
                [ , label=right:Dead End]
                [ , label=right:Dead End]
            ]
        ]
        [ 
            [ 
                [ , label=right:Dead End]
                [ 
                    [ , label=right:Dead End]
                    [ 
                        [ , label=right:Dead End]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [ , label=right:Dead End]
        ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without many changes in your code, you can define a `sibling distance` per `level`in the `tikz options`, to avoid the branches overlay. In addition, you can also define the global `grow` of the tree in the same options.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,
grow=right,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=2.75cm,},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.45cm,},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.6cm,},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=0.4cm,},
]
\node {Start O}
    child{node{O}  
        child{node{O}  
            child{node{O}  
                child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
                child{node[anchor=west]{O Success Node}}  
            }  
        child{node{O}  
            child{node{O}  
                child{node{O}  
                    child{node{dead End}}  
        }}}}  
        child{node{O}  
            child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
            child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
            child{node[anchor=west]{O dead End}}  
        }  
    }%-----------------------------  
    child{node{O} 
        child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}  
        child{node{O}  
            child{node{O}  
                child{node{O}  
                    child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}}
                child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}}  
            child{node[anchor=west]{dead End}}}  
    }
;  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If it is  not a problem for you, I recommend you to use the [`forest`](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) package, which is based on the `tikz` package, instead of solely the `tikz` package.

I hope there is no mistakes with the tree branches.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={% style of tree nodes
                grow=east,
                anchor=west, parent anchor=east,
                s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
                l sep = 8mm,   % level distance
                edge path={
                    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}]
                    (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)
                    \forestoption{edge label}; %edge/node connection
                },
            }
            [Start O
                [O
                    [O
                        [O
                            [O
                                [O
                                    [dead End]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                        [O
                            [O Sucess Node]
                            [O dead End]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [O
                        [O dead End]
                        [O dead End]
                        [O dead End]
                    ]
                ]
                [O
                    [O
                        [dead End]
                        [O
                            [dead End]
                            [O
                                [dead End]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [dead End]
                ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are a lot of possibilities to customize your tree with `forest`, see please the documentation.

A minimal change to improve the readability is changing the edge path, for example:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={% style of tree nodes
                grow=east,
                anchor=west, parent anchor=east,
                s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
                l sep = 8mm,   % level distance
                edge path={
                    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}]
                    (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0pt) |- (.child anchor)
                    \forestoption{edge label}; %edge/node connection
                },
            }
            [Start O
                [O
                    [O
                        [O
                            [O
                                [O
                                    [dead End]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                        [O
                            [O Sucess Node]
                            [O dead End]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [O
                        [O dead End]
                        [O dead End]
                        [O dead End]
                    ]
                ]
                [O
                    [O
                        [dead End]
                        [O
                            [dead End]
                            [O
                                [dead End]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [dead End]
                ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Package `forest` seems very powerful. Your `edge path` option should be a possible standard option in the package.

Comment: i am using Miktex 2.9, and forest package is giving error "missing inserted for ifnum <to be read again> \requiredpackageexpl3

Comment: For me my MWE compiles with `TeXLive 2019` as well as `Miktex 2.9`. Does the error appear with my MWE or when you have implemented my MWE in your code?  Is your `TeX` distribution up to date? It seems to be related to a package that loads `expl3`.